# sbrk(0) isn't always returning the same value

Tags: c, memory

I've been tasked with coding an implementation of the buddy allocation algorithm. I'm not very comfortable with C and my understanding of pointers isn't all that great. I'm trying to code a custom memory allocater with the following:

When I first try to allocate memory I use the following:

```
    head = sbrk(0);
    printf("%p\n",sbrk(0));
    sbrk(MAX_SIZE);
    head = malloc(sizeof(head) + size);
    head->free = false;
    head->data = malloc(size);
    head->size += size;
    head->next = (void*)sbrk(0);
```

MAX_SIZE is a given and head is a custom struct. In the beginning it's uninitalized. For some reason by head->next value and the sbrk(0) printed in the beginning don't always match up. Sometimes they'll both be equal to the same thing eg:
0x7e357000
but other times my head->next will take a much larger value such as :0xffffffffa4d8b000. There seems to be no reason why these values only matchup sometimes. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Perhaps `malloc` is implemented using `sbrk` semantics?

Comment: You're mixing levels.  If you want to build an allocator on top of `malloc()` then do so, but if you're going to build one based directly on manipulating the program break then you're basically taking full responsibility, and `malloc()` should be left out of it.  Not only out of your allocator itself, but probably out of the whole program.

Comment: You should use mmap()/mremap() for the underlying memory space of your own allocator instead of using `brk()`/`sbrk()`, so you don't collide with malloc().